# Вывести третий уровень вложенности в меню OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart, ocstore

На сайте OpenCart 2.3.0.2 выводится мобильное меню через модификатор, но в нем только 2 уровня вложенности. Что прописать в коде чтобы добавить третий уровень вложенности?

```
      <div>
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
                <ul>
                      <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
                      <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
                      <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
                      <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
                      <?php } ?>
                      <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            <?php } ?>
      </div>
```